# laravel 4 returning validation message error

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I am currently just testing laravel 4, but i have a problem, in the laravel docs returning error messages is described this way `$messages->first('email');`should return the message, but no matter what methog id try on the `messages` i get error

my cobtroller

```
public function postSignup()
    {
        $rules = array(
            'display_name'     => 'required|unique:users',
        );

        $messages = array(
            'display_name.required' => 'Felhasználónév kötelező',
            'display_name.unique'   => 'Ez a Felhasználónév foglalt',
        );

        $val = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);

        if ($val->passes()) 
        {
            $data = array('msg' => 'yay');
        }
        else
        {
            print_r($messages->first('display_name'));
        }

        return Response::json($data);
    }
```

{"error":`{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to a member function first() on a non-object"`

if i try with `all` just for a test  print_r($messages->all()); im getting the following

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to a member function all() on a non-object"
```

could please someone point out what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this

```
if ($val->passes()) 
{
    $data = array('msg' => 'yay');
}
else
{
    $messages = $validator->messages();
    $data = array('msg' => $messages->first('display_name'));
}
return Response::json($data);
```

`print_r(...);` in the `controller` will print the output outside of the template. On the client side you can check the `msg` something like this (using `jQuery` for example)

```
$.get('url', function(data){
    if(data.msg == 'yay')
    {
        // success
    }
    else
    {
        // failed, so data.msg contains the first error message
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your help, i was confused using L4 after L3 a little bit

Answer (score 0):

Validator::make method only accepts two arguments.

Comment: No, `Validator::make` method accepts three arguments. Third one is optional.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the messages array you passed into the validator, not the error messages the validator created. Change your code to this:

```
$val->messages()->first('email')
```

NOTE: The validator::make method accepts 3 arguments:

```
/**
 * Create a new Validator instance.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @param  array  $rules
 * @param  array  $messages
 * @return \Illuminate\Validation\Validator
 */
public function make(array $data, array $rules, array $messages = array())
```